# how to access local files on Webfaction server?

Tags: python, django, webfaction

I am trying to access a file on Webfaction using:

```
    f = file(filepath,'rb')
```

where filepath is : home/rgh/webapps/trsaastrarium_django/filebrowser/files/TRSA Schematic/Maisam architects & engineers/H4-Dims(201-206).pdf.

I tried to accessed the file using ftp and the path is correct , but i keep getting (no such file or dir), this works fine on my machine but not on webfaction.
am i doing anything wrong ?

Comment: In your case, the filepath should start with '/' since it's an absolute path.

Comment: it worked ! you are right. post it as an answer to get more points